# I am trying to create template using c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, linker

I have a problem with linker. I am trying to create template Tree but since I'm having some problems with using templates (my first time) I decided to do a "test template program". I have been looking for anserws before posting and tried some solutions posted on the forum but none has worked for me. Here is the test program:

.h file

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(T value);
    ~Node();
    void manualTree();
private:
    T data;
    Node *left, *right, *parent;
};
```

.cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(T val) {
    data = val;
}

template<class T>
void Node<T>::manualTree() {
    Node* root = new Node(1);
    root->left = new Node(2);
    root->right = new Node(3);
    cout << "left : " << root->left->data << endl;
    cout << "right : " << root->right->data << endl;
    cout << "root : " << root->data << endl;

}

template class Node<int>;
```

main body

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "arithmetics.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Node<int> n;
    n.manualTree();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what i get after trying to call manualTree() function:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State

```
Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  zad6 - szablony C:\Users\Piotr\source\repos\zad6 - szablony\Debug\zad6 - szablony.exe   1   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Node<int>::~Node<int>(void)" (??1?$Node@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  zad6 - szablony C:\Users\Piotr\source\repos\zad6 - szablony\zad6 - szablony\main.obj    1   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Node<int>::Node<int>(void)" (??0?$Node@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main   zad6 - szablony C:\Users\Piotr\source\repos\zad6 - szablony\zad6 - szablony\main.obj    1   1
```

EDIT:

I have moved everything to the .h file, like they said in the linked post and i still get the same warnings sometimes with a few more. Already tried putting into .cpp file these lines and still not working (with the same warnings):

```
template class Node<int>;
```

or

```
Node<int> n;
```

new .h file

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(T value) {
        data = value;
    }
    ~Node();
    void manualTree() {
        Node* root = new Node(1);
        root->left = new Node(2);
        root->right = new Node(3);
        cout << "left : " << root->left->data << endl;
        cout << "right : " << root->right->data << endl;
        cout << "root : " << root->data << endl;

    }
private:
    T data;
    Node *left, *right, *parent;
};
```

Comment: Implementing your member functions in the header file is simplest solution.  Alternately you can explicitly export particular template instantiations

Comment: after moving implementation to the header file i get  exactly same message with one more linker problem as a bonus. By implementing in header file, you mean not even creating .cpp file and doing everything in .h file, right?

Comment: Templates are not like java generics. They need access to the source code during compile time. Unless you only want to explicitly instantiate a few types its best to put all code (for template objects/functions) in header files.

Note there are workarounds to this but unless you really want to ensure your code is not public, its generally not worth it.

Comment: I moved the whole implementation to .h file and implementation looks like above at "new .h file section" and I am still having the same problems with linker. I don't know what i am doing wrong at this point.

Comment: Read your errors they specifically say you do not have definitions of your 
default constructor `Node();` and destructor `~Node();`

Comment: Wow, so this is, what those messages meant. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: No problem, if you call manualTree() make sure you create a destructor that  can handle deleting the nodes you created otherwise you create a memory leak.

Comment: Also I am assuming you are using VisualStudio (because of #pragma once) I *highly*  recommend disabling language extensions. Language extensions in Visual Studio allow you to create code that is not C++ standard (and it comes to bite you in the but if you ever switch to writing in a linux enviroment (which I also recommend))

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, it is nice to learn something ;)